# possible combinations for given characters in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a task where I need to find all possible combinations of given characters.

This is my input string:

```
"{a | b} {c | d} e {f | } g {h | i}"
```

Here characters in `{}` indicates alternate possible characters seperated by pipe `|` symbol at that position. So for this input the possible ouputs are as below:

```
a c e f g h
a c e g h
b c e f g h
b c e g h
a d e f g h
a d e g h
b d e f g h
b d e g h
a c e f g i
a d e f g i
a d e g i
b c e f g i
b d e f g i
b d e g i
```

How can we implement this in Java?

I tried using a for loop but not able to figure out how to find all possible combinations?

**Update:**

Tried using a recursive call, but not working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "{a|b} {c|d} e {f|} g {h|i}";
        String[] array = in.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String data = array[i];
            recursivecall(data);
        }
    }

    private static void recursivecall(String data) {
        if (!data.startsWith("{")) {
            System.out.println(data);
        } else {
            String set = data.replace("{", "").replaceAll("}", "");
            System.out.println("set = " + set);
            String[] elements = set.split("\\|");
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                recursivecall(elements[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting output as:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=find+all+possible+combinations

Comment: So, you want to simply generate things like `aaaaa`, `aaaab`, `aaaac` etc? While I don't think this would be the most efficient, for loops could do this quite easily.

Comment: "using a for loop" doesn't really tell us anything about what you did.  You need to include your code, along with how you ran it, and the expected vs actual output for us to be able to help you fix it.  As it's written now, your question sounds like you're asking someone to write it for you.

Comment: @Frontear, no I gave what I need as output in my question

Comment: Ah, youd like to randomly pick something from `{char | char}`, and iterate the rest? `{a | b} {c | d}` would be `ac, ad, bc, bd`?

Comment: @SLaks, even I tried that but I need it in different way, where only the elements in `{#|#}` will be repeated, where as if the text is not inside `{}` then I need them to be printed without any condition as mentioned in my above example

Comment: @Frontear, yes something like that, if the elements are not surrounded by `{}` then they need to be present in output without any condition.

Comment: First, youll need to parse the actual text for anything with {}, however I'd recommend you read up on permutations, specifically factorials, and then generation of ordered combinations. These will greatly help you in this.

Comment: The number of left braces in your input is greater than the number of right braces. Moreover, it is not clear why `acegi` and `bcegi` was not included in your expected output.

Comment: @JohnMcClane, my bad, by mistake I added the extra open brace, I corrected it. Yes I need `acegi` and `bcegi` also, I tried to add all possible combinations, I missed these

Comment: @Frontear, I am able to get them separately as texts, now I need to form different outputs as mentioned in my question, can you suggest some urls which can guide me through this?

Comment: You could parse the string into a tree, adding a node by possible alternation of the current token to each nodes of the previous level. Then you'd just have to recurse through that tree to build the set of possible combinations. I'm pretty sure there'd be a more optimal datatype to help with your problem (lots of redundancy with the tree), but it'd sure work

Comment: @Aaron, can you please suggest a good example on it, I am not clear how it can be achived

Comment: Let's say the input is just `{a|b}{c|d}`. You parse the first token, `{a|b}`, you add two nodes `a` and `b` to the root node. You parse the second token, you add two nodes `c` and `d` to both the `a` and `b` nodes. You're done, so you now recursively browse your tree to build the output set : you first call your function on the root node with a set containing the empty string. For each element of the set, the function should create the concatenation of the element plus your current node, so for the first step `["a", "b"]`, then `["ac", "ad", "bc", "bd"]`

Comment: @Aaron, can you please help me with an example, I am not able to build a tree as you are explaining

Comment: Then don't bother with the tree and use Dawood's answer, it's better unless you need to do multiple things with the input and want to avoid parsing it all over again.

Comment: @Aaron, I tried Dawood's answer, updated my question based on it. I followd his steps but I am missing something, its not working. So wanted to try with tree approach as well

Comment: Your method should return something, you're missing an important part of recursive calls that is building on the next (or previous) step. A tree won't help, it's just an additional intermediate representation. I'd suggest you try your hand at recursion on computing factorials, it's a great example to get to understand recursion

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to use recursion for this; so you'll be writing a method that potentially calls itself.  The logic will be something like this.

- If the input doesn't contain any `{` characters, then just print it directly.  This is your base case.
- Otherwise, pick just one of the `{ }` sets.  If there are nested pairs, then pick one that doesn't have any `{ }` sets inside it.
- Iterate through the elements in the chosen, calling your method where the argument is the result of replacing the set with the element.

For example, if your method argument is `"a{b|c|d}e"`, you would iterate through the `{}` set, and recurse into your method three times - the arguments each time would be `"abe"`, `"ace"` and `"ade"`.

The recursion would make sure that every possibility would be chosen, for every `{ }` set.  This handles any number of elements within each set, and any level of nesting of sets.

Comment: Thank you, I tried placing your points as a code for my program but I am missing something, the program is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. I assume that only single letters and empty strings (like the second part in `{f | }`) are considered valid variants. No nested braces are allowed.

This is non-recursive solution. The most important part in it is the `while` loop inside `compose()` method. On each iteration, it replaces the `combList` list (which initially contains only one empty string) with variations of it obtained by adding all possible combinations of the next available character given in the input string. Note that you can swap two `for` loops inside the `while` loop to obtain the same set of combinations, but in a different order.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CharCombinations {
    private final String input;
    private int pos;

    private CharCombinations(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    private String[] checkChoice(String[] choice) {
        String[] chars = new String[choice.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : choice) {
            String t = s.trim();
            switch (t.length()) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (Character.isLetter(t.charAt(0))) // internationalized
                        break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a letter: " + t);
            }
            chars[i++] = t;
        }
        return chars;
    }

    private String[] nextCharChoice() {
        while (pos < input.length() && input.charAt(pos) == ' ')
            pos++;
        if (pos == input.length())
            return null;
        char c = input.charAt(pos++);
        if (c != '{')
            return checkChoice(new String[]{String.valueOf(c)});
        int closBracePos = input.indexOf('}', pos);
        if (closBracePos < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No matching delimiter: "
                + input.substring(--pos));
        String delimChoice = " " + input.substring(pos, closBracePos) + " ";
        if (delimChoice.trim().isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty variants list");
        pos = ++closBracePos;
        return checkChoice(delimChoice.split("\\|"));
    }

    private List<String> compose() {
        List<String> combList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        combList.add("");
        String[] choices;
        while ((choices = nextCharChoice()) != null) {
            List<String> newCombList = new ArrayList<>(combList.size() * choices.length);
            for (String c : choices)
                for (String comb : combList)
                    newCombList.add(comb + c);
            combList = newCombList;
        }
        return combList;
    }

    public static List<String> combinations(String input) {
        return new CharCombinations(input).compose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : combinations("{a | b} {c | d} e {f | } g {h | i}"))
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than simply giving an answer, perhaps explain it instead? User won't benefit from code they can't understand.